# Above-the-counter oven vs. microwave - do these exist?

Tags: stove, range

I know what an over-the-range microwave is but for this kitchenette I'd like an over the countertop oven-only with the same clearance.  Do such configurations exist?  What are the code implications and typical rules.  I have searched and my searches always lead toward microwaves.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about putting a stove at roughly head height like where a microwave would commonly be mounted?  I'd think those wouldn't exist since it would be very difficult to actually use.  If that's not what you mean, can you describe it a little more, or perhaps add a drawing of what you're thinking of?

Comment: You can get a combination convection oven/microwave for over-the-range. I've had a couple of them. They're nice to have.

Comment: If you mean "oven" search for "wall oven" not "over the counter oven." I you mean stovetop burners, there's a Flanders&Swann song with a line praising the convenience of an eye level broiler so you don't have to bend over to get hot fat in your eye...

Comment: As noted in other comments, your use of the word _"stove"_ here is very confusing. It causes your question to be unclear, and unanswerable as-is. Please [edit your post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/180768/edit) to explain either why the word _"stove"_ is actually what you meant and how you expect to use this _"over-the-counter stove"_, or change the word _"stove"_ to whatever word it is you actually mean.

Comment: Thanks Greg Nickoloff and @Ecnerwal for your correct terms and guidance.  Searching by "wall oven" yielded what I wanted. Sorry, I have changed the word oven to stove.